# Error in SQL Syntax using Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, foreign-keys

Something is wrong with the code I have down below. Checking for SQL Syntax validators online reveal something is wrong with the last line. I cant figure out what though.

```
CREATE TABLE module3.eventrequest (
`EVENTNO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
`DATEHELD` DATE NOT NULL,
`DATEREQ` DATE NOT NULL,
`CUSTNO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
`FACNO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
`DATEAUTH` DATE NOT NULL, 
`STATUS` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`ESTCOST` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`ESTAUDIENCE` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`BUDNO` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_EventNumber PRIMARY KEY (EventNo)
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNO) REFERENCES customer(CUSTNO)
)
```

Any Ideas? Using MySQL workbench.

// I've updated the code to use references. I have a table customer with CUSTNO as primary key.

Comment: You are missing the `references` part of the definition.

Comment: What do you mean? Still very new to this language, I apologize. I've added this line, it doesnt seem to help : REFERENCES EventNo(EventNo))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wasted an hour, and learned it the hard way. "," can absolutely ruin your life, and thats what all I was missing. A simple comma.
Fixed code:

```
CREATE TABLE module3.eventrequest (
`EVENTNO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
`DATEHELD` DATE NOT NULL,
`DATEREQ` DATE NOT NULL,
`CUSTNO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
`FACNO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
`DATEAUTH` DATE NOT NULL, 
`STATUS` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`ESTCOST` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`ESTAUDIENCE` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`BUDNO` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_EventNumber PRIMARY KEY (`EventNo`),
CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerNumber FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTNO`) 
REFERENCES customer(`CUSTNO`)
)
```